# Cannot open projects in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When trying to open any .csproj in Visual Studio 2008 (Windows Vista), I am faced with the following error:

Unable to read the project file 'zzz.csproj'. The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Doing a search for this error seems to indicate that most other users saw this when VS couldn't find a specific runtime DLL, but having traced this error with ProcMon, this does not appear to be my issue.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VS2008, but that did not fix the issue either.

Answer (score 0):

Long-shot, but...

Are you sure that you installed the Visual Studio Web Developer components when you installed Visual Studio?

I've skipped that component before, figuring that it was it was a Visual Studio Express Web Developer type thing (that I figured wouldn't need because I was installing the full-blown VS).  However that component installs the core support for web projects, so after that I couldn't open any web projects because VS didn't recognize the file format.  Reinstalling with the web components turned on fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately resorted to doing a System Restore, and that resolved the issue. I think it was that traces of a Beta where not properly uninstalled, but neither the error message nor ProcMon were able to help me out. I really wish the error message was more specific.